# Storing data in the session when authenticating a user

Tags: .net, session, forms-authentication

I currently have an IHttpModule that is doing some custom forms authentication to authenticate a user with my single sign on server.  After redirecting back from my SSO server, I get a bunch of information about the user. I'd like to store this in the Session as opposed to the FormsAuthenticationTicket because the amount of data is large. However, in the AuthenticateRequest event it does not appear that the session is setup yet. Is there a good way around this or a better way to store the data. I'm also not thrilled about the fact that the session and FormsAuth data would necessarily be in sync time-wise so I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting it in the Global.asax Session_Start event handler.

Comment: Can I still authenticate the user here?

Comment: I believe so... I'm not positive though. I believe you can access the user the same way as you would in AuthenticateRequest. Give it a shot and let me know if it works. I'm kind of curious now...

Comment: Is there any way to access this event handler programmatically? I'd like to just have my HttpModule register this event itself through the HttpApplication object.